# Group Rectangles function to detect vehicles OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, detection

Below is the output and code for a surveillance camera footage (which included background subtraction). May I know how do I add in group rectangles function and draw rectangles(to track every vehicles in every single frame)? Thank you! :)

Output > [Output][1]
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1TLu.png `

```
using namespace cv;     
using namespace std;
const char* params
   =     "{ input          | background.mp4    | Path to a video or a sequence of image }"
      "{ algo           | MOG2              | Background subtraction method ( MOG2) }";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, params);


//create Background Subtractor objects
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> pBackSub;
if (parser.get<String>("algo") == "MOG2")
    pBackSub = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();

VideoCapture capture(parser.get<String>("input")); //input video



Mat frame, fgMask;
while (true) {
    capture >> frame;
    if (frame.empty()) //break if frame empty
        break;
    //update the background model
    pBackSub->apply(frame, fgMask);

    //erode the frame with 3x3 kernel
    Mat frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel;
    erode(fgMask, frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3,3)));

    //dilate the frame with 2x2 kernel
    Mat frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel;
    dilate(frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel, frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2,2)));

    //show the current frame and the fg mask
    imshow("Frame", frame);
    imshow("FG Mask", fgMask);
    imshow("After eroded with 3x3 kernel", frame_eroded_with_3x3_kernel);
    imshow("After dilate with 2x2 kernel", frame_dilate_with_2x2_kernel);
    //get the input from the keyboard
    int keyboard = waitKey(30);
    if (keyboard == 'q' || keyboard == 27)
        break;
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to track foreground in video and draw rectangle on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32531713/how-to-track-foreground-in-video-and-draw-rectangle-on-it)

Comment: @Spinkoo No, this is another problem - Multitarget tracking. The classic decision - Hungrian algorithm for data assotiation. For example: https://github.com/Smorodov/Multitarget-tracker . The most modern approaches - data flow algorithms based on work Zhang, Li, Nevatia: Global data association for multi-object tracking using network flows"

Comment: ah okey , but for drawing part i suppose its the same & finding contours